# MySQLdb on MAC OS 10.6.8

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I'm having a lot of troubles with MySQLdb installation on MAC 10.6.8 I read many guides on how to solve without success.

Answer (score 0):

What's the output on:

`# which python`

`# which pip`

If pip is installed try:

```
# pip install mysqldb
```

Comment: `host918:~ avafab$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
host918:~ avafab$ which pip
host918:~ avafab$ pip install mysqldb
-bash: pip: command not found
host918:~ avafab$  
`